# How can I store hashed password on database with Django?

Tags: django, hash, passwords

I want to make the textbox input starred while typing in the password, also I want the password to be saved in the database as a hashed password.

**The View**

```
class UserCreate(CreateView):
    model = ModelUser
    fields = ['first_name', 'password', 'username', 'dob', 'email', 'unit', 'house', 'road', 'suburb', 'state', 'postcode', 'country', 'id_type', 'id_no']
```

**URLConf**

```
url(r'^add_user/$', views.UserCreate.as_view()),
```

**The Model**

```
class ModelUser(AbstractUser):
    client_id = models.IntegerField(null=True)  #id_client in voipswitch database
    user_type = models.CharField(max_length=15, default='client')
    dob = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, default=0)
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    house = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    road = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True)
    suburb = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True)
    postcode = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    id_type = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True)
    id_no = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    reg_time = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, default=datetime.datetime.today())

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.phone
```

Comment: This question is already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098466/how-to-store-django-hashed-password-without-the-user-object)

Answer (score 1):

So, using a `CharField` for the password

```
password = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
```

allows you to use a `PasswordInput` in the form that makes the UI "star" it.

```
password = forms.PasswordInput()
```

Then to store the password hash into the database under password, you need to make sure it's a string, not bytes. Django's [internal hashers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/contrib/auth/hashers/) mentioned by others will return strings by default. If you use something like [scrypt](https://bitbucket.org/mhallin/py-scrypt/) (I'm assuming Python3), be sure to decode it before storing it to the DB:

```
import scrypt, os, base64

def generate_password(length=255):
    chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
    return ''.join(choice(chars) for _ in range(length))

user.password = base64.b64encode(scrypt.encrypt(
    generate_password(datalength), user.password
))
user.save()
```

And later to verify it...

```
try:
    scrypt.decrypt(base64.b64decode(user.password), 'guessed_password')
    return True
except scrypt.error:
    return False
```

*Note - an encoding issue with scrypt I encountered is tracked [here](https://bitbucket.org/mhallin/py-scrypt/issues/20/python34-str-input-and-password-not).*

Comment: Why not `make_password` in django?

Comment: @MohammedShareefC you can use that too and in most cases it's simpler, although scrypt is not available there and some crypto nerds prefer scrypt to defend against some types of attacks – https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/8159/what-is-the-difference-between-scrypt-and-pbkdf2