# How to store Django hashed password without the User object?

Tags: django, passwords

I have a Django application that allows web visitors to create there own accounts. Once they create an account with a passwords, they should receive and email containing activation code. When a web-visitor creates a new account, they need to receive an activation email containing a unique key.

Obviously, I can do all this using Django's built-in authentication system. I've done it before without any problems. However, in this application, I don't want to pollute my Users table with inactive users. I only want activated users to appear in the Users table. So although I will use Django's account system for authenticating activated users, until they become activated, I'm rolling my own system. I'm keeping all the data about not-yet-activated users in a separate Django Model object (called `UserActivation`). And I will be managing the sending of the activation email myself.

The problem I'm having is that I don't want to store the user-submitted password in Plain text. I want to store it in my UserActivation object in a field called "password" in the same hashed-format it would appear in the User table. To put it into the user object, I would have done `myUser.set_password("plainTextPassword")`. How can I get this same value and stuff it into `UserActivation.password`?

From looking at [**this**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/) doc, it seems that there is a `make_password()` function that returns the value that I need. But I still need a User object to call that method. How can I conver `"plainTextPassword"` to hashed password without going through the User object?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You are on the right track. However you can manage the password manually using

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
print "Hashed password is:", make_password("plain_text")
```

Hasher configuration will be driven by PASSWORD_HASHERS which should be common for both the auth system and your UserActivation model. However you can pass it in `make_password` method also.

```
PASSWORD_HASHERS = (
    'myproject.hashers.MyPBKDF2PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2SHA1PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptSHA256PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptPasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.SHA1PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.MD5PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.CryptPasswordHasher',
)
```

Hope this helps.

Read this link for more details: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/passwords/

Answer (score 45):

The accepted answer was helpful to me - I just wanted to add the check_password call (for people like me, who haven't used this functionality before)

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password, check_password

hashed_pwd = make_password("plain_text")
check_password("plain_text",hashed_pwd)  # returns True
```

Comment: small point to note that make_password returns a string (albeit invalid for the built in login) even if pw is None. Built in login checks if it starts with UNUSABLE_PASSWORD_PREFIX  constant.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it recently by doing the following steps:

```
from .models import Client
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
from .forms import ClientForm

form =  ClientForm(request.POST)

if form.is_valid():
    
            first_name      = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
            family_name     = form.cleaned_data['family_name']
            password        = make_password(form.cleaned_data['password'])
            phone           = form.cleaned_data['phone']
            
            user    =   Client(first_name=first_name, family_name=family_name, password=password, phone=phone)
            user.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

**views.py**

from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password, check_password

print("password hashing!!!!")

```
    password = make_password('password')
    print(password)
    signup_obj = Signuup(firstname=first_name,
                         lastname=last_name,
                         email=email,
                         password=password)
    signup_obj.register()
```

**password = make_password('password')** that will convert the password to hash but must use that code of line before register/save the object....

[image: here is the hash password saved in database]